# I put 3 pokemon im 3 different gym's, but now all 3 pokemon are gone! hos to Get back?

Tags: pokemon-go

I put 3 pokemon om 3 different gym's, but now all 3 pokemon are gone! and the app says that i dont have a pokemon in a gym..

is there someone who knows how to Get them back??

Comment: What do you mean by "gone"? Are they not in the gym anymore?

Answer (score 4):

When a gym is downsized or defeated and your Pokemon are kicked out, they return to your Pokemon inventory. (Actually, they are always visible in your Pokemon inventory; the ones in gyms have a special tag next to them indicating they are at a gym.) You don't have to do anything to "get them back".

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting your Pokemon by HP, they will be at the bottom of the list because they were defeated. You'll have to use a Potion to bring them back up to full health. Take a look at your bag inventory, select one of your Potions and you'll see a list of Pokemon that fit the criteria for using one or the other. Tap on one to bring it back up to full health.

Comment: Not sure the edits are accurate, I'm almost sure I've had to use Revive on Pokemon that return to me defeated from a gym.